# Do you need to close a key using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

All of the examples of using an S3 key in boto omit the `close` method, but I can see it is there in the API. Should one call `close` after writing a file to a key, or is it not necessary? i.e. is line 3 necessary:

```
key = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name).new_key(filename)
key.set_contents_from_string(data)
key.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 does not have the concept of a file that is "open" or "closed". It either exists (in whole), or it doesn't exist.

The `set_contents_from_string()` function creates the object and stores the data. The object cannot be incrementally updated.